# Morphia equivalent of this java-driver code

Tags: mongodb-java, morphia

I want to do this in morphia. Can anyone help out

```
Bson f1 = Filters.gt("score", 80);
Bson f2 = Filters.lt("score", 100);
Bson f3 = and (f1, f2);

MongoCursor<Document> c = collection.find(
                                     elemMatch("grades", f3))
                                    .iterator();
```

please do note that the following does not work

```
ds.find(Restaurant_M.class)
          .field("grades.score")
          .greaterThan(80)
          .lessThan(100)
          .asList();
```

my goal is to get all the documents where the score in the grades sub-document is only BETWEEN 80 and 100. it should $and the $gt:80 and $lt:100. The morphia statement which i posted only checks every individual score for both conditions. it does not check all the scores in a $and. so i get documents where the score is e.g. 130 (because it is > 80).

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use AND operator to handle this:

```
Query<Restaurant_M> query = getDs().find(Restaurant_M.class);
query.and(query.criteria("grades.score").greaterThan(80),   query.criteria("grades.score").lessThan(100));
List<Restaurant_M> orders = query.asList();
```

Using morphia version 1.2.0

Comment: sorry, that still doesn't work. it is also returning a restaurant with has a grade = 131. Note: restaurants have more than one grade.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I looked at morphia source code and didn't find answer on the question. It seems current version doesn't support multiple criteria for array of documents. Also I registered an [issue](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/970) on morphia github.

Comment: thought so too. thanks. i have done it using hasAnyOf()